# PHP Image Resize (gallery)

Tags: php, path, gallery, php-gd

I've recently built a website using PHP for the first time. I have create a gallery script using various tutorials which automatically pulls through images held in a set location and creates a thumbnail, if one does not exit.

Now my upload works fine as does pulling through the images, however the script for some reason, will not re-size the image! This is really beginning to baffle me now and as I have never used php before, I am at a total loss. My script it below

```
<?php
    # SETTINGS
    $max_width = 100;
    $max_height = 100;

    function getPictureType($ext) {
            if ( preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext) ) {
                    return 'jpg';
            } else if ( preg_match('/png/i', $ext) ) {
                    return 'png';
            } else if ( preg_match('/gif/i', $ext) ) {
                    return 'gif';
            } else {
                    return '';
            }
    }

    function getPictures() {
            global $max_width, $max_height;
            if ( $handle = opendir("Design/Images/Gallery/") ) {
                    $lightbox = rand();
                    echo '<div id="gallery"><ul>';
                    while ( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                            if ( !is_dir($file) ) {
                                    $split = explode('.', $file); 
                                    $ext = $split[count($split) - 1];
                                    if ( ($type = getPictureType($ext)) == '' ) {
                                            continue;
                                    }
                                    if ( ! is_dir('Design/Images/Gallery/thumbs') ) {
                                            mkdir('Design/Images/Gallery/thumbs');
                                    }
                                    if ( ! file_exists('Design/Images/Gallery/thumbs/'.$file) ) {
                                            if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
                                                    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                                            } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
                                                    $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                                            } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
                                                    $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                                            }
                                            if ( ($oldW = imagesx($src)) < ($oldH = imagesy($src)) ) {
                                                    $newW = $oldW * ($max_width / $oldH);
                                                    $newH = $max_height;
                                            } else {
                                                    $newW = $max_width;
                                                    $newH = $oldH * ($max_height / $oldW);
                                            }
                                            $new = imagecreatetruecolor($newW, $newH);
                                            imagecopyresampled($new, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newW, $newH, $oldW, $oldH);
                                            if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
                                                    imagejpeg($new, 'Design/Images/Gallery/thumbs/'.$file);
                                            } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
                                                    imagepng($new, 'Design/Images/Gallery/thumbs/'.$file);
                                            } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
                                                    imagegif($new, 'Design/Images/Gallery/thumbs/'.$file);
                                            }
                                            imagedestroy($new);
                                            imagedestroy($src);
                                    }
                                    echo '<li><a href="Design/Images/Gallery/'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']">';
                                    echo '<img src="Design/Images/Gallery/thumbs/'.$file.'" alt="" />';
                                    echo '</a></li>';
                            }
                    }
                    echo '</ul></div>';
            }
    }
```

?>

I believe the error is something to do with my paths but I am not sure, can anyone shed some light on this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Simply pass the parameter in below function n u'll get the resized image.

for Ex.

$sourcefile = SITE_PATH."pro_images/".$main_img_name;

```
$thumb = "thumb_".$main_img_name;   

$endfile =  SITE_PATH."pro_images/thumb/".$thumb;

    $thumbheight = 80;

    $thumbwidth = 80;

    $quality = 75;




function createThumbs($sourcefile, $endfile, $thumbwidth, $thumbheight, $quality){
```

preg_match("'^(.*).(gif|jpe?g|png)$'i", $sourcefile, $ext);

switch (strtolower($ext[2])) {

```
   case 'jpg' : 

   case 'jpeg': $img  = imagecreatefromjpeg ($sourcefile);

                 break;
   case 'gif' : $img  = imagecreatefromgif  ($sourcefile);

                 break;
```

case 'png' : $img  = imagecreatefrompng  ($sourcefile);

break;

}

//$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourcefile);

$width = imagesx( $img );
$height = imagesy( $img );

$scale = $thumbwidth/$width;

```
$newwidth = ceil($width * $scale);
$newheight = ceil($height * $scale);
```

// Create a new temporary image.

$tmpimg = imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );

// Copy and resize old image into new image.

imagecopyresampled( $tmpimg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );

// Save thumbnail into a file.

imagejpeg( $tmpimg, $endfile, $quality);

}

Comment: Sorry to be stupid but I'm really confused by this (i'm a total newbie!). Am I missing something in my own code?

Comment: If the problem is regarding path than you should give absolute path of image folder may this will help  you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, managed to find a solution using absolute paths.